# How to override npm project config?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a nodejs project and placed .npmrc file at root to override default npm config. I need to change the npm project config while building the project. Is there any option available to override the npm project config?

I tried to run this

```
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

but it couldn't override the npm project config.

Answer (score 2):

To override use `--registry`

sample format 
     `npm --registry registryurl install packagename`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is very old. However, I believe that the project specific `.npmrc` file overwrites your global `.npmrc` file, not the global overwriting the project as you seemed to mention in your question.

From my research, it appears that there is no project-specific argument for the `npm config set` command. It only works on the global file, I think...

I found success by just running all the `npm config set <key> <value>` commands I needed, going to my global `.npmrc` file and copying all the new key/value pairs, pasting those into my project specific `.npmrc` file, then going back and deleting those new key/values from my global `.npmrc` file.